# Modules working in Pycharm but not Shell or Command Line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and having trouble with several modules. In Pycharm, everything works fine. I am able to import modules, pip installer works fine. However, for some reason I'm running into issues when trying to import modules in the Python Shell, or when running programs using the command line. 
For example, I can import Beautiful soup just fine in pycharm, but when I try in the shell I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import bs4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Similarly, when I save a program in pycharm and try to run it from the command line, I get:

C:\Users\Tony>hellowness.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tony\MyPythonScripts\Hellowness.py", line 3, in 
    import selenium, bs4, pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

The correct directory is being used, because I can run simple programs that don't use modules without problems in the command line. 
Sorry if this has been answered eleswhere. I searched the forum but people seem to being having trouble installing modules. The modules are installed fine (I think) they just don't work in the Python Shell or the command line. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Thank you,
Tony

Comment: Do you use a virtual environment that you forgot to activate?

Comment: You almost certainly have two Python installations. BeautifulSoup is installed in the one and not in the other. Look in PyCharm to see where your Python interpreter is. Then check that the Python you run from the command line is the same. Installing a module in one version of Python doesn't make it available in other versions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Do you mean two different versions? Both appear to be 3.7.2

Comment: And I do have a virtual environment in Pycharm. There'sa venv folder

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. As you said there were two "Site Packages" directories installed. One for Pycharm and one for Python itself. I am sure there's a more efficient way to solve it, but for now I just copied any relevant modules from Pycharm's site packages folder over to Python's.

Thanks!